# $(c^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\phi(x)=0$ not Lorentz-invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation

I have a question about the following passage on pg. 89 of Zee's QFT in a nutshell:

> At first sight, what Dirac wanted does not make sense. The equation is supposed to have the form "some linear combination of $\partial_\mu$ acting on some field $\psi$ is equal to some constant times the field." Denote the linear combination by $c^\mu\partial_\mu$. If the $c^\mu$'s are four ordinary numbers, then the four-vector $c^\mu$ defines some direction and the equation cannot be Lorentz invariant.

The simplest equation I can construct that he is referring to is

$$(c^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\phi(x)=0, $$

for $m>0$. Taking $\phi(x)\rightarrow\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$, and $c^{\mu}\rightarrow\Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \ \nu}c^{\nu}$. Then, the left term transforms like

\begin{align*}
\Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \ \nu}c^{\nu}(\Lambda^{-1})^{\sigma}_{\ \ \mu}\partial_{\sigma}\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x) &= \delta^{\sigma}_{\ \ \nu}c^{\nu}\partial_{\sigma}\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)\\
&=c^{\sigma}\partial_{\sigma}\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x).
\end{align*}

Then, we have that

$$ (c^{\sigma}\partial_{\sigma}-m)\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)=0.$$

But doesn't this show that the equation is Lorentz-invariant?

Comment: Well, no. But doesn't Zee say that we care about it being invariant for SOME vector $c$? Couldn't we just choose a vector with all nonzero components?

Comment: Related? [Invariance, covariance and symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/61351/9887)

Comment: For this same problem, I find the argument in Peskin and Schroeder on the fact that we want to obtain the KG equation when we "square" the Dirac equation more convincing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "breaking Lorentz invariance".  As you say, it is certainly true that if you're given a vector $c^\mu$ at some point, you can construct Lorentz scalars from that vector (that is, objects that transform covariantly under Lorentz transformations).  The point Zee is getting at is this: physically, a theory being Lorentz invariant means that there is no notion of a preferred reference frame.  But if you specify some vector $c^\mu$ at a point, you automatically obtain a preferred reference frame constructed from it (for example, if $c^\mu$ is timelike, you can define a preferred reference frame as the one in which $c^t$ is the only nonzero component).  So while something like $c^\mu \partial_\mu$ may transform covariantly, any object you construct from $c^\mu$ cannot be Lorentz-invariant because the presence of $c^\mu$ chooses a preferred frame.

(By the way, the fundamental issue here has to do with needing to specify $c^\mu$ *by hand*; you can remedy the situation by, for instance, upgrading $c^\mu$ to be a dynamical vector field which is not fixed a priori but is instead determined as a solution to some equations of motion.)

Comment: I see what you're getting at, I believe. So you're making a distinction between "transforming covariantly" and being Lorentz-invariant. It seems that, in the literature, when they say "let's prove such and such is Lorentz-invaraint", all they do is check to make sure that transforms covariantly. They never mention anything about "checking for vectors" or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the distinction I'm making.  While I do wish this distinction was clearer in the literature, I suspect the reason people use "transforms covariantly" as synonymous with "Lorentz-invariant" is that as a general rule, you almost *never* impose a field (vector or otherwise) by hand (there are exceptions to this that I won't get into, though).  If no fields are specified by hand, then transforming covariantly *does* imply Lorentz invariance.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. So could you answer for me? If an equation contains an invariant tensor, then the equation can be Lorentz invariant? For example, in $2+1$ spacetime dimensions, $\epsilon^{uvp}\partial_u A_p+mA^v=0$ can be Lorentz invariant? Here $\epsilon^{uvp}$ is a levi-civita tensor with $\epsilon^{123}=1$. I know that this levi civita tensor is an invariant tensor in any coordinate systems. Thus does this make the equation I wrote Lorentz invariant?

Comment: Yes, that equation is indeed Lorentz invariant.  Another example is the Laplacian $g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu$, where $g^{\mu\nu}$ is the (inverse) metric tensor.  In fact, if $A_\rho$ is the vector potential for an electromagnetic field, then the object $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho} \partial_\nu A_\rho$ is the dual of the electromagnetic field tensor, since $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho} \partial_\nu A_\rho = \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho} (\partial_\nu A_\rho - \partial_\rho A_\nu)/2 = \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho} F_{\nu\rho}/2 = (\star F)^\mu/2$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, whenever you're in doubt, a more reliable way of doing transformations is, instead of replacing things by other things, defining a new coordinate $x'^\mu = \Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu$ and finding equalities. In this case we have that $\partial_\mu = (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu_\mu \partial'_\nu$, so let's take the equation

$$(c^\mu \partial_\mu - m) \phi(x) = 0$$

and use the two equalities I wrote in the above paragraph:

$$(c^\mu (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu_\mu \partial'_\nu - m)\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x') = 0$$

We can use that $c^\mu (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu_\mu = \Lambda^\mu_\nu c^\nu$, so that, if we define $\phi'(x') = \phi(\Lambda^{-1}x')$, we have

$$(\Lambda^\mu_\nu c^\nu \partial'_\mu - m)\phi'(x') = 0$$

So the transformed field $\phi'$ doesn't satisfy the original equation, because you need to transform the components of $c$.

Comment: In reference to your first and second sentences, I have heard different. For instance, in Peskin, to show that an equation is Lorentz invariant we show that if an equation is satisfied by $\phi(x)$ then it is also satisfied by $\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$ under a Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Javier: Right, but if $c^\mu$ is a Lorentz vector (as it had better be if the equation has any chance of transforming covariantly), then its components do indeed transform as required for your field $\phi'$ to obey the original equation in the new coordinates.

Comment: Oh, I see. I made a mistake. Since we are still evaluating this equation in the old coordinate system, i should not take $c\rightarrow \Lambda c$.

Comment: The equations look 'different' because that's precisely what you'd expect to happen with the transformation. (As a reference, compare with $(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu+m^2)\phi(x) = 0$.) The problem is what happens with the $c^\mu$, not the argument of $\phi$. This answer is pretty fundamentally flawed - the answer is correctly given by Sebastian.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty that's a good point, but I think the rest of my answer is valid; Sebastian correctly explains why one would expect this equation to not be invariant, but doesn't go into the math. I show explicitly what happens when you change coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You could argue that the $c_\mu \partial^\mu$ term must be a scalar. But then note that different observers would disagree about the constants $c^\mu$, as that ‘constant’ would obviously depend on the frame of reference. So the equation would look different to different observers, breaking the principle of relativity, viz (from wiki)

> 1. First postulate (principle of relativity)
>
> The laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames of reference.

You could get round this by promoting the constant $c^\mu$ to a dynamical vector field, which ultimately leads to a gauge theory.

You could say that they are constants that don’t transform as a four-vector. That would also break relativity, as it wouldn’t be Lorentz invariant.