# What Lorentz covariance has to do with Lorentz invariance?

Tags: symmetry, tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry, covariance, invariants

Does saying that the Dirac equation is invariant under Lorentz transformations is the same as saying that it is Lorentz covariant?

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: Related:  [Invariance, covariance and symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61347/invariance-covariance-and-symmetry)