# Invariance and covariance

Tags: symmetry, definition, covariance, invariants

What exactly do we mean when we say that something is covariant?
How is it different from being invariant?

Am i right if I say that the word invariant is used when we're talking about a physical quantity (example-length and momentum 4-vectors are Lorentz invariant).
Whereas the word covariant is used when we're talking about equations.

I'm a bit lost with the terminologies.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61347/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7700/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, covariant means that an object transforms covariantly. This means that it transforms along with the basis vectors (co- means with, or along).

If the basis vectors transform like
$$\tilde {\mathbf e}_i={\mathbf e}_j{F^j}_i$$
Then a *covariant* vector is something whose *components* transform using the same matrix.
$$\tilde \omega_i=\omega_j{F^j}_i$$
A *contravariant* vector, which we often think of as a regular vector, transforms with the inverse of this matrix. It transform against (contra) the basis vectors.
$$\tilde V^i={B^i}_jV^j$$
where $B$ is the inverse of $F$, or in other words $B\cdot F=1\!\!1$ or ${B^i}_j{F^j}_k=\delta^i_k$. I used $F$ for the forward transformation and $B$ for the backward transformation. Check out [this playlist  on youtube by Eigenchris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ptMTLzV4-I&list=PLJHszsWbB6hrkmmq57lX8BV-o-YIOFsiG&index=1&ab_channel=eigenchris) for a more in-depth explanation using the same notation.

But... the word covariant is also used often to denote something that is invariant under such transformations, as can be seen [enter link description here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors#Informal_usage). So covariant could mean either what I meant above or it could mean that something is invariant.

Note that vectors are invariant as well under a change of basis. The vector components change, but the vector as a whole stays invariant. You can write
$$\mathbf V=V^i\mathbf {e}_i$$
where $V^i$ transforms covariantly, but $V$ doesn't transform. You can check that $\tilde{ \mathbf V}=\mathbf V$

To make things even more complicated there are active and passive transformations. A passive transformation is like a change of basis, like I mentioned before. Vectors do not transform under passive transformations. An active transformation means that vectors change as well. As an example you could lay down a magnet on your lab table. The magnetic produces a magnetic field $\mathbf B$ around the magnet. If we now rotate our lab table we perform an active transformation on $B$: we rotate each vector with the same angle as we rotated the table.

Usually the author specifies at the beginning of a book if the transformations are active or passive and if they don't they deserve to stub their toe on a heavy table.